# Trouble installing rgeos

Tags: r

I can't install `rgeos`.

```
> install.packages('rgeos')
...
configure: CC: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp
configure: CXX: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -fopenmp
configure: rgeos: 0.5-3
...
checking for geos-config... /usr/local/bin/geos-config
checking geos-config usability... yes
configure: GEOS version: 3.8.1
checking geos version at least 3.2.0... yes
checking geos-config clibs... yes
checking geos_c.h  presence and usability... no
configure: error: geos_c.h not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
```

I'm on Mac OS 10.15.6 and installed geos 3.8.1 with homebrew. It's linked. `geos-config --includes` returns the location of `geos_c.h`. I tried to install from source and pass its location.

`R CMD INSTALL ../rgeos_0.5-3.tar --configure-args='--with-geos-config=/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.8.1_1/bin/geos-config'`

Still no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related? https://github.com/r-spatial/lwgeom/issues/34 (I know it's not the same package, but perhaps the flags can help)

Comment: I tried adding some of the flags they suggest, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with install.packages("sf") on AWS linux. Assuming you work with linux RStudio, you must start in sudo mode your Rstudio

> $ sudo rstudio

or if you only work with R:

> $ sudo R

then try to install your package with this instruction

```
install.packages("geos", type = "source",
                 configure.args=c("--with-proj-lib=/usr/local/lib/",
                                  "--with-proj-include=/usr/local/include/",
                                  "--with-geos-config=/usr/local/bin/geos-config",
                                  "--with-gdal-config=/usr/local/bin/gdal-config"
                 ));
```

Assuming you know where geos-config, proj, and gdal are installed ... so, try to install these heavy R-packages as a super-user in RStudio and/or R. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using conda environments:

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-rgeos
```